# r raster Can I combine two raster bricks directly?

Tags: r, r-raster

I want to combine two (or more) raster bricks. Here's an example of what I want to do

```r
library(raster)

r <- raster(ncol=40, nrow=20)
r[] <- rnorm(n=ncell(r))

b1 <- brick(x=c(r, r*2, r))
b2 <- brick(x=c(r, r*3, r))

b <- brick(b1, b2)
```

This example returns the following error.

> ```
> Error in (function (cl, name, valueClass)  :    assignment of an
> object of class “RasterBrick” is not valid for @‘nlayers’ in an object
> of class “.MultipleRasterData”; is(value, "integer") is not TRUE
> ```

If I create stacks instead of bricks as follows

```
b1 <- stack(x=c(r, r*2, r))
b2 <- stack(x=c(r, r*3, r))

b <- brick(b1, b2)
```

I get the following error message

> ```
> Error in if (values) { : argument is not interpretable as logical
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You need `stack` to combine multiple rasters, stacks, or bricks that have the same extent and resolution into a single multi-layer object.  Then you can convert to a `brick`

```
s <- stack(b1, b2)
nlayers(s)
#[1] 6
b <- brick(s)
print(b)

class       : RasterBrick 
dimensions  : 20, 40, 800, 6  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 9, 9  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       :  layer.1.1,  layer.2.1,  layer.3.1,  layer.1.2,  layer.2.2,  layer.3.2 
min values  :  -3.604523,  -7.209047,  -3.604523,  -3.604523, -10.813570,  -3.604523 
max values  :   3.441872,   6.883743,   3.441872,   3.441872,  10.325615,   3.441872
```

See https://www.rspatial.org/raster/spatial/4-rasterdata.html#rasterstack-and-rasterbrick for more info

Comment: I have been doing the first part of the response, ie `s=stack(b1, b2)`. The second part `b <- brick(s)` works fine for small stacks. But when I attempt to do this with some real (and really large) data it takes a very long time. Since the main purpose of converting to brick was to speed up some other calculations I was hoping to make everything into bricks and combine those. Seems like this is not possible.

Comment: What if you write the ```stack``` to file using ```writeRaster``` and then read back in as a ```brick```, which would then just point to that one file?  Not really sure...just an idea.

Comment: To make this faster, use ClusterR, it lets you use more cores for raster functions!

Comment: stackApply may also help speed things up for you https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/3.0-7/topics/stackApply